# How do you use input type="image" in Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js

In a VueJS template I can use

```
<img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/lj-logo.svg" />
```

However when I use the same image in `input type="image"` as

```
<input type="image" src="./assets/lj-logo.svg" alt="Search" />
```

I get this 
[image]

Is it a VueJS bug or I just need to do something to work around it like

```
<input type="image" :src="require('./assets/lj-logo.svg')" alt="Search" />
```

which looks kinda clunky.

Comment: Right-click that element and click `inspect`. From there, can you tell us how is the input element rendered as HTML?

Comment: `<img alt="Vue logo" src="/img/lj-logo.5b355605.svg">`

Comment: So it's not rendered as an input element?

Comment: How did you set vue up? Did you start with something like Vue CLI 3? If so webpack is expecting your assets in a public folder by default and doesn't process any paths that originate there.

Comment: Sorry, I gotta ask the obvious question - `/img/lj-logo.5b355605.svg` actually exists right? There's no compile shenanigans remapping things going on? That broken image icon means the browser is getting a 404 error.

Comment: try copying the path of your image and play with the route but replacing it with "../"

Comment: All I know is the work around with `require` works and it also renders the same image path.  Also I misread the earlier comment the rendered element was `<input type="image" src="./assets/lj-logo.svg" alt="search" >` so no translation.

Comment: i think you can't directly use the src path in the input tag...... you need to convert to some type of blob url

Comment: @ProClasic yes that's my workaround.  It was just clunky because Img src does not need it.